# How can I upload file to the field in cypress? But field's type is text

Tags: cypress

I used different ways. But can not handle.

```
cy.get('#form-group-936cd4f5-19ab-4f3c-bfd9-563bf46212b3 > .fal')
        .click()    
        .attachFile('files/sample.pdf', {force: true})

cy.get('#form-group-936cd4f5-19ab-4f3c-bfd9-563bf46212b3 > .form-control)   
        .attachFile('files/sample.pdf', {force: true})

cy.get('#form-group-936cd4f5-19ab-4f3c-bfd9-563bf46212b3 > .fal')
        .attachFile('files/sample.pdf', {subjectType: 'drag-n-drop'})
```

**HTML**

```
<div _ngcontent-ete-c120="" class="form-group upload-doc ng-star-inserted" id="form-group-936cd4f5-19ab-4f3c-bfd9-563bf46212b3">                         <label _ngcontent-ete-c120="" class="ng-star-inserted">Please provide bank account statement</label><!---->                         <input _ngcontent-ete-c120="" type="text" readonly="" class="form-control ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid"><i _ngcontent-ete-c120="" class="fal fa-upload"></i>                         <!---->                          <!---->                       </div> –
```

**Hidden file upload input**

```
<input _ngcontent-juf-c120="" type="file" ng2fileselect="" class="uploader" accept="application/pdf,application/acrobat,application/nappdf,application/x-pdf,image/pdf,image/jpeg,image/pjpeg,image/png">
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nyaxv.png)

Comment: What do you mean by "can not handle"? If the field is indeed a text field, it looks pretty obvious to me that you cannot upload a file

Comment: Yes, it's type is text. But in UI manually I can add files.

Answer (score 0):

cypress-file-upload only checks `type="file"` for `subjectType: 'drag-n-drop'` option, the default `subjectType: 'input'` does not check.

Cannot tell it your test are any good, there not enough info given (except the 3rd will not work).

Pause and inspect the DOM after #1 & #2, to see if there's a valid attachment DTO.

But attaching the file is only part of the story, you will need to find out what event is used and `.trigger()` it.

Comment: There is a hidden file upload in html. But it works after clicking the field. How can I handle it?

Comment: Show the HTML structure

Comment: `<div _ngcontent-ete-c120="" class="form-group upload-doc ng-star-inserted" id="form-group-936cd4f5-19ab-4f3c-bfd9-563bf46212b3">
                        <label _ngcontent-ete-c120="" class="ng-star-inserted">Please provide bank account statement</label><!---->
                        <input _ngcontent-ete-c120="" type="text" readonly="" class="form-control ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid"><i _ngcontent-ete-c120="" class="fal fa-upload"></i>
                        <!---->

                        <!---->
                      </div>`

Comment: Please layout in the question to make it readable.

Comment: Sure done already

Comment: Sorry, there's no hidden input there -  you must be mistaken about that.

Comment: The field is the file upload that I am doing in UI. But the type is "text", as u can see. And it is not working to upload files to this field in cypress. I talked with the developer and he told me that there is a hidden HTML element.

Comment: Ask your developer to show you the hidden element - obviously you need it.

Comment: Added hidden input to the layout

Comment: So now just use that hidden input (forget about the type="text" input). Don't forget to check out if any event needs to be triggered.

Comment: With invoke-command I got the file upload field and attached my file. But now the file name didn't appear in the type field place. That is why we can not continue. Added picture to the label